# Efficient mapping of values to pixels with the same label

Tags: python, mapping

I'm trying to create an image in which all pixels in each patch (i.e. each group of pixels with the same label) have the same value (previously calculated). In other words, I have:

- A label matrix/image "L", in which the value of each pixel is the label assigned to it;
- A vector "V" with length equal to the number of labels and containing the values to map the pixels to;

I'd like to create a new matrix/image in which each pixel has the value in "V" corresponding to the label it has in the "L".

I already tried the obvious which is cycling through each label, finding the pixels with that label and assigning them the corresponding value in V:

```
L= [[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2],
    [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2],
    [0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2]]
L = np.array(L)
V = [7,8,9]
totLabel = np.amax(L)
result = np.zeros( (L.shape), dtype=np.float32 )
for idx in range(0,totLabel):
    result += (L==idx)*V[idx]
```

This works, in the sense that the result is as expected:

```
result:
[[7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9],
 [7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9],
 [7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9],
 [7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9]]
```

The problem is that now i need to upscale this to images of size 11000x11000. This makes it extremely slow since with my code at each iteration a new numpy matrix of that size is allocated (label==idx) and de-allocated and i have to repeat this process for something like 150k unique labels.

EDIT: added example values and expected output.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a minimum working example and show what you expect your output to be? I'm not sure I quite understand what you are trying to do. I feel like you might want to look into boolean indexing (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the bad example. Added better example as requested. "L==idx" does already create a Boolean mask of sorts. I could write "result[bool_mask]=V[idx]" and it would work, but the creation of a new mask at each iteration is the reason why this code is so slow.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
labels = np.unique(L)
L_copy = L.copy()

for label in labels:
    mask = (L_copy==label)
    L[mask] = V[label]
```

This directly modifies L though. If you don't want that then you need to copy the array first.

Comment: This is not a viable solution because it creates a new boolean mask for each label. As stated in the question, in the final code I have to deal with 150k labels and an image of about 120MP, meaning I would saturate the RAM. Besides that I don't think it would fasten up the code since I still wastes time allocating every single mask.

Comment: Sorry I misread that part. I have edited my answer so that the mask are only created on the fly. Hope that helps.